# Git connect using ssh on windows

Tags: windows, git, github

I have read some questions around but still didn't found the solution to this problem

I have git on windows and I want to connect to github using ssh.
Following this tutorial https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
I have successfully setup my keys

If I open a git-bash and try to ssh github I am able to connect, so this works

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

this means that git-bash actually sees my keys. However if I try to do a push

```
git push origin master
```

git prompts me for username and password
Thank you for your help

EDIT: solved by using the git protocol instead of the http protocol, my fault
so replace this

```
https://github.com/_user_/_repository_.git
```

whit this

```
git@github.com:_user_/_repository_.git
```

in the remote link

Comment: Did you set it up with PUTTY? Do you have pagent running?

Comment: Close, but possibly inexact, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962222/git-1-7-10-asks-me-for-github-username-and-password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably cloned a remote that uses the https protocol, rather than the git protocol. You need to redefine your remote for *origin*.

```
# Change this as needed.
github_username="$LOGNAME"

# Replace your remote, then push.
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin "git@github.com:${github_username}/${PWD##*/}.git"
git push --tags --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to remove/add, just do something like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```